# Почему в C# классы не поддерживают ковариантность и контрвариантность?

Tags: c#, generics, clr

Почему только интерфейсы и делегаты в C# поддерживают технику ковариантности и контрвариантности в  Generic типах?

Comment: а что еще должно поддерживать?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2733346/4928642

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Хороший вопрос.

Простой, поверхностный ответ — потому что это до сих пор не было имплементировано в языке. Но возникает вопрос, почему это не было имплементировано? Смотрите.

Дел в том, что C# появился как чисто императивный язык, в котором основной тип структур данных — мутабельные (то есть, *изменяемые*) структуры данных. Теперь представьте себе, что у вас есть класс `C<out T>`. Что вы будете делать с типом `T`?

Вы не можете иметь метод с входным параметром типа `T`. Потому что вследствие `out` у вас может в качестве входного параметра реально прийти тип, базовый для `T` (по смыслу контравариантности, поэтому-то и используется ключевое слово `out`: `T` может встречаться только в «исходящих» позициях, в качестве возвращаемого значения).

То же относится и к публичным свойствам типа `T` с сеттером (и полям), т. к. это по сути та же функция, принимающая на вход `T`.

Вы не сможете иметь полезное приватное мутабельное поле типа `T`. Почему? Подумайте, как вы присвоите ему какое-нибудь новое значение. Откуда вы его возьмёте? У вас нету методов, которые принимают на вход `T`, по описанным причинам, вы можете лишь самостоятельно сконструировать экземпляр. Так что ваше поле типа `T` будет скорее всего бесполезно.

Без мутабельных полей типа `T`, много ли будет пользы от такого параметра? Вот поэтому разработчики языка и решили не заморачиваться с поддержкой контравариантности для классов. С ковариантностью по сути та же история, только вместо невозможности записи в поле типа `T` вы столкнётесь с невозможностью *чтения* из него: ко- и контравариантность симметричны.

---

Сейчас язык C# развивается в сторону большей поддержки функционального стиля программирования, в котором популярны иммутабельные (неизменяемые) структуры данных. Если ваша структура данных иммутабельна, вы вполне можете сделать её контравариантной по параметру. Пример лучше всего посмотреть [здесь](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/12/06/immutability-in-c-part-three-a-covariant-immutable-stack/) (`+T` читать как `out T`). Поэтому стоит рассчитывать, что поддержку вариантности для классов добавят в следующих версиях языка.

---

Идеи ответа одолжены из [ответа Эрика Липперта](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2734070/276994), разработчика ко- и контравариантности в C#.